# Getting error - "tightvncserver: Could not create /home/pi/.vnc"

Tags: raspbian, vnc, raspbian-jessie

I am using `raspberry pi 2` with `Jessie` raspbian release. I had installed `tightvncserver` using following command -

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

However, when i try to start the server using command line i get following error -

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
tightvncserver: Could not create /home/pi/.vnc.
```

But the server starts when i run command - `sudo tightvncserver`. Any help on how to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though your language and locale are not set. Try running `sudo raspi-config` and under #4: Internationalization Options change the locale to the appropriate setting. As for the reason that using `sudo` works but not using `sudo` doesn't is probably that the file that `tightvncserver` is trying to create:`/home/pi/.vnc` can't be created with the privileges that you have, but when run as superuser, those permissions errors don't happen. I believe that you always run `tightvncserver` as root (ie. sudo), although I may be incorrect.

Comment: I tried setting Internationalization options and locale warning was resolved, but the error from tightvncserver still exists. Not sure why it is asking me to run with root privileges as i didnt install it with root user logged in. Thanks